# Why can I access data values directly from a sequelize model?

Tags: javascript, mysql, orm, sequelize.js

So my question is pretty simple, if you do a single select in sequelize it will return a model. If you print out that model you can clearly see that model has a bunch of options, dataValues, _prevValues, _change, _options, isNewRecord etc. However what is bizarre to me is that you can also access the data values directly, for instance.

myModel.myCustomAttribute will work, but based on the data structure I would have to type myModel.dataValues.myCustomAttribute.

How does sequelize do this and what aspect am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

One case is in getter methods. If you need the value in the getter method, and you use this.myProperty, you will get a recursion problem. Instead you could use this.dataValues.myProperty. Example:

```
var Article = db.define('article', {
  title: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notEmpty: true
    }
  },
  content: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    allowNull: false
  },
  tags: {
    type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.TEXT),
    defaultValue: []
  }

}, {
  getterMethods: {
    tags() {
      return this.getDataValue.tags.join(', ');
    }
  }
});
```

In this case, if you instead tried to use:

```
  getterMethods: {
    tags() {
      return this.tags.join(', ');
    }
  }
```

You would get a recursive mess since tags() calls itself.